# Unit Testing Mere Mortals .NET Framework

Tags: .net, unit-testing

Assuming a client already has chosen to use the Mere Mortals Framework from Oak Leaf Software, what would be the recommended approach to allow for unit testing and proper separation of concerns for the resulting application?  Ideally I'd like to achieve something like SOLID design principles and have layers that are not all completely coupled to a database.  My knowledge of MM.NET is still introductory - has someone dealt with this issue and if so can you identify the seams in the framework that make it possible (dare I hope easy?) to achieve this from the system?

Answer (score 0):

First, read up on [the other threads on unit testing.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing), including a couple good gems here:

- [What makes a good unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61400/what-makes-a-good-unit-test)
- [What's the best way of testing private methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/whats-the-best-way-of-unit-testing-private-methods)
- [How do you know what to test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62625/how-do-you-know-what-to-test-when-writing-unit-tests)
- [Beginning TDD Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24965/beginning-tdd-challenges-solutions-recommendations)

See what applies to your project, directly.

Specifically, when using a framework, determine what you need to test.  Do you trust the framework and vendor?  Then don't worry too much about unit testing their code.  You can assume there's a testing boundary there - they've made sure their stuff is right.  It's up to you to make sure *your* code is right.

Other than that, developing unit tests for your code using MM.NET won't be any different than developing code for any other application library; follow some of the advice in the other questions, and you should do fine.

Comment: Thanks Robert - I'm looking to be able to unit test my business logic without having it depend on the database.  My initial thought is that this will be difficult with MM.NET.  I'm not new to unit testing, only to this framework.  Have you used it?